# Is it possible to change wireless router BSSID?

Tags: networking, security, router, wifi

I suspect someone is trying to hack our wireless network.  I've stopped broadcasting the SSID, but assuming they've already attempted to gain access in the past they could have the BSSID stored, which should allow them to continue their attempts (correct?).

Is there a way I can also change my BSSID?  This is a mediabridge router.

Comment: Turning off the broadcasting of SSID as a security enhancement has been debunked a hundred times.

Comment: See my comment below. I'm not concerned with security, I don't think they can hack the network. But they have presumably spent some time working on it, as we've had disruptions I believe were attempts to hack the network for the past week or so. I disabled broadcast of the name to make the network harder to identify, presumably they have some time already committed and will want to continue their effort.  The BSSID is still out there, so they should be able to identify it easily. I want to change it so they are less tempted to continue.

Comment: Turning off broadcasting will not solve that either. It doesn't make your WiFi network undetectable.

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: Eh, never mind. I suggest you go read some of the extremely detailed write-ups on the myth of hiding your network.

Comment: I suggest you read some of the extremely helpful books on English. I haven't suggested that it's possible to hide the network. :)

Answer (score 3):

From what i know, changing BSSID is hardware related. So, unless you provide some details regarding your router, i doubt you'll get much help.

Now, considering your main goal is to protect your `wlan`, using `WPA2` with a 63 chars passphrase will do a way better job than hiding/changing SSID/BSSID.

Comment: The problem I'm having is the interference caused by the individual bombarding the network with traffic.  I don't want them to know where I am anymore and to be able to switch BSSID when necessary upon subsequent attacks.